# JSP : getRequestDispatcher does not forward to other jsp files

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to forward my error message back in my login page if user keys in the incorrect password. It works for the first try, but when user retype password regardless of the right or wrong password, it will then return me HTTP Status 404 
For an example , in user login JSP .. If user is log in as user, 
I will do a condition that it will sendRedirect to user page.    where else if user is sign in as Admin , it will sendRedirect to Admin page.  ---- This part , it is working perfectly good , i am using dispatcher ----

For an example in the code structure i did 
**login.jsp**

```
<form action="../loginController" method="post">
    <p> Username : <input type="text" id="name" name="username" required/</p>
    <p> password : <input type="text" name="password" required/> </p>
    <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>


<h2><%=request.getAttribute("errorMessage") %></h2>
```

/*--  It should redirect back to this page when user keys in the wrong password . which in the url should input it as .../login.jsp  ---*/ 
/*--

I created a servlet file , i call it loginController . My user data i retrieve is from oracle. Everything from fetching of data is perfectly fine
The only problem is when im doing the condition.


---*/

Servlet is **loginController.java**

```
      if(loginRS.equals("user")){
           response.sendRedirect("User/User.jsp"); /*--This is working --*/

       } else if(loginRS.equals("admin")){
           response.sendRedirect("Admin/Admin.jsp"); /*--This is working --*/

       } else if(loginRS.equals("IncorrectPassword")) {

           /*--- This is where the problem starts ---*/
           RequestDispatcher rd =                 
           request.getRequestDispatcher("./Login/login.jsp");
           request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Username Not found");
           rd.forward(request, response);
```

/*--Up till here, the code is working , the only problem is that it is storing inside servlet.java rather than to forward it back to login.jsp--*/

/*-- This is where the problem starts, When i key in the wrong password , it returns errorMessage as username not found. BUT in my urlPath , it states that it is still inside LoginController. if in the second try , i were to input the correct password , it return me 404 page not found --*/

I thought of putting this code below to redirect it back to login.jsp if the condition is called. but i am unable to sendreDirect it.
               response.sendRedirect("./Login/login.jsp");
           }

Thank you in advance

**SOLVED**
Basically the problem I was facing was my connection , hence its leading to error 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `./` or `.` from `request.getRequestDispatcher("./Login/login.jsp");`